# Subequations and align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, numbering, amsmath, align

I am trying to use `subequations` with a complicated alignment. The alignment in the MWE is not satisfactory. I am seeking for a solution where I can specify `lrc` such as in `array`, but `subequations` doesn't work with `array` like `equation` does. Is there a way to get the features from both sides: subequations numbering and referencing; and flexible alignment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
I+J & \to & K & + & L & A \\
    & \to & M & + & N & B \\
    & \to & O & + & P & CA
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lllllc}
I+J & \to & K & + & L & A \\
    & \to & M & + & N & B \\
    & \to & O & + & P & CA
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `*align*` environments aligns its columns `rlrlrlrl…`. In this case, you should use `alignat` or `aligned` (if its only on equation with three lines and not three separate equations) where you “jump” over one column by using `&&`.

Comment: But does it work with `subequations`? And flexible alignment?

Comment: Hihi, but does it blend? :D Sorry. If you only use `&&` in `alignat` you only get the `r` or the `l` columns. (`alignat` doesn’t add spacebetween the `l` and `r` columns like `align` does (because `align` is made for equations with two parts (the left-hand and the right-hand side). The `c`entering is more tricky but with `mathtools` you get an excellent tool for it: `\mathmakebox`/`\mathclap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this approach come close to your desired output?

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{3}
I+J & \to K && + L &\qquad \mathmakebox[\widthof{$CA$}][c]{A}  \\
    & \to M && + N &\qquad \mathmakebox[\widthof{$CA$}][c]{B}  \\
    & \to O && + P &\qquad \mathmakebox[\widthof{$CA$}][c]{CA}
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I have to do a test in the real code. I tell you latter. I just don't get the `3` after the `alignat`, is it the number of columns, because I have more than `3`?

Comment: `6` minus `1`? wouldn't it be `4` `$`'s minus `1`?

Comment: @cacamailg Err, my comment is totally absurd. It should read: “The `3` stands for: number of `&` plus 1 divided by 2. Or: number of sub-equations (in one *row* like in `align`).” We’re missing one right-hand side, so there are actually five alignment points/`&`. But you can easily use `99` there without any complaint, I think.